# How to paint brick and galvanized flashing together?

Tags: painting, paint, roofing, masonry

I recently changed the chimney flashing on my house and removed a lot of old roofing tar around the flashing. This caused some discoloration on the bricks, so I'd like to do what the previous flashing had and paint the discolored bricks and flashing a brick color.

What would be the proper method and materials be for doing this? I was thinking:

1. Clean galvanized metal with vinegar to remove zinc
2. Wash w/ warm water and soap
3. Apply two coats of primer
4. Apply two color coats
5. Apply two clear coats

[image]

Comment: maybe you want to roughen the zinc with sand paper for better adhesion

Comment: But not too much, or you might cut *through* the zinc!